# Pool connect failed : java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I have a spring application and created as ear and deploying in Web-logic server. in my application i configured my  dataSource using jndi. in the code i am fetching some records and calling oracle bpm application which is running in another server. in my server i have cross domain for bpm server like this

```
type=<remote>, protocol=cross-domain-protocol, remoteHost=bpmdev_domain
```

here the problem is i am getting above exception. when i comment the bpm part it is running fine. but i want to call bpm method. can any body tell me what i am doing wrong. am i missing any configuration in my spring.xml or my server or in my code while calling bpm.

here is my exception stack trace

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Pool connect failed : java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[bpm_weblogic1, AdminChannelUsers, Administrators, AppTesters, CrossDomainConnectors, Deployers, Monitors, Operators, OracleSystemGroup, keyStoreRole]
```

here is my spring.xml

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="MCDataSource"/>
   <!--  <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="dsJndiTemplate" /> -->
    </bean> 
      <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="MCDataSource"/>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
 <property name="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>
</bean>


 <!-- <tx:advice id="txAdvice"  transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <tx:attributes>

      <tx:method name="*"/>


      </tx:attributes>
   </tx:advice>
     -->
   <!-- <aop:config>
      <aop:pointcut id="createOperation" 
      expression="execution(* com.tcs.controller.BpmService.*(..))"/>
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="createOperation"/>
   </aop:config> -->

    <!-- <bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@173.19.7.200:1521/OIM.xyz.gov.in" />
    <property name="username" value="name"></property>
    <property name="password" value="pass"></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </bean> -->


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

here when i use datsource2 it is working fine but with jndi it is not working.
and here i want to know that what is the difference between fetching the connection from jndi and datasource.